# can we use isset() function on $argv[1] in php ,

Tags: php

can we use isset() function on $argv[1] in php, so that if input is not during script execution then $a can take empty value otherwise it takes input provided. I have written this code below wanted to know if we can do this ?

```
$a = isset($argv[1])?$argv[1]:"";
```

Comment: Have you tried? Does it work?

Comment: why not just `$a = $argv[1] ?? '';`?

Comment: Ask yourself, - having read the manual for isset(): why do you think it _wouldn't_ work? $argv is no different to any other array (aside from the way it gets populated). And as mentioned above...have you tried it? What was the result? Did you have an actual problem? It's really unclear what you need from us, we are not here to do basic tests on your code when you haven't tried it yourself yet.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your array because if you want to check [1] then your array length must have to 2 otherwise it will through an error.

```
$a = $argv[1] ?? ""; // you can use it for not showing any error is your array is empty
```

Comment: What is "_then your array length must have to 2_" supposed to mean? `$argv[0]` will always be set (the name of the script)

Comment: suppose you have an array $a=[]; but you check $a[1] which does not exist that's why if you wnt to use $a[1] then your array at least has to $a[1,2] 2 element.

Comment: Hm, not really. You can have an array `$a = [];` and only have `$a[1] = 'test';`. You could even have `$a[12] = 'test';` and not need 13 elements. And as mentioned, `$argv[0]` **always** exists, it's the name of the script

Comment: then i think you have to explain more about your issue.

Comment: I don't really have an issue, I'm not OP.